# What would $('div, span', $('.test')).selector output? jQuery bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have something similar to the following selector:

```
$('div, span', $('.test')).selector
```

I expect the selector that is produced to be:

```
.test div, .test span
```

But its actually produces

```
.test div, span
```

What gives? I need the result to as expected otherwise its a huge headache.

Comment: Is it actually the selector thats wrong? or the fact that it selects the wrong elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it a bug? Well...it's debatable.  It's not *reliable* in these situations (and many others), but per [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/), it doesn't have to be.

`.selector` though accessible, [isn't a supported or docunmented part of the API](http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=.selector), so it may do some strange and unsupported things.

The short version: it won't so what you're after here, because it's designed for much simpler situations (usually one level deep), like [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) use [internally](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/event.js#L528).

---

*Edit:* If anyone's curious as to the *why* part of this, it's just how it's written, what you have: `$('div, span', $('.test'))` [is actually doing](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L173) a `$('.test').find('div, span')` [which calls `.pushStack()` underneath](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/traversing.js#L33), which is *very* simple: [only appending a space and the new selector](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L239).

Comment: @BoltClock - nope, it's always behaved this way, making it an actual CSS selector would be quite hard (and not even possible in any custom cases, e.g. `:contains()`)

Comment: I'm not sure that your edit is correct. It actually gets the right results. Surely .selector should parse out the commas?

Comment: @Schotime - I'm not following...it *doesn't* get the right results (that's the whole problem the OP has), it gets `.test div, span`, the "correct" result would be `.test div, .test span` as a CSS selector.